# Why does $2$ appear in $95\%$ confidence intervals?

Tags: normal-distribution, linear-regression, confidence-interval

I was told that, in linear regression, the $95\%$ CI for $\beta$ is $$\beta \in \left(\hat\beta-2 \sigma,\hat\beta+2\sigma\right), \text{ where } \sigma = \text{standard error}(\hat\beta).$$

**My question**: Where does the $2$ come from?

Also, would that $2$ change if, say, we were looking for a $90\%$ CI, or $40\%$ CI?

I recall that the level of confidence affects the $t$-value cutoff for hypothesis testing, but I can't recall how it changes in the above context.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's because $$2\approx 1.96 \approx \Phi(0.975),$$

where $\Phi$ is the cumulative distribution function of the standard normal distribution $Z\sim N(0,1)$, that is,

$$\mathbb{P}(Z<1.96)\approx 0.975$$

The number even has its own [wikipedia article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/1.96). Note: always draw the picture.

If you want a $100(1-\alpha)\%$ confidence interval, you should use

$$\mathbb{P}\left(-\Phi\left(1-\frac{\alpha}{2}\right)<Z<\Phi\left(1-\frac{\alpha}{2}\right)\right)=1-\alpha.$$

Comment: ok I see, so just to make sure I understand, for example if I wanted 90% CI, I would want $\phi\bigg(1-\frac{.1}{2}\bigg)=\phi(.95)=1.65$, and here 1.65 would be the coefficient next to $SE[\hat\beta_1]$?

Comment: That is correct.